# Serialize data is too big

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I serialize the data for every player server side and it's about 128kb in size. I serialize a [255,255] array of bools which is a must for mapping, what alternatives could I use as I heard gzip would actually increase the size?

I have heard about protobuf-net but it's undocumented and no examples exist on the internet.

Comment: No, GZipStream won't increase that size.  You fight FUD by actually trying it.

Comment: @Hans well, it *can* do, depending on how random the data looks. Assuming a good implementation that *spots* that the data is random, you still have the overhead of a frame header. A bad implementation (that doesn't spot that it is random) could do just about anything.

Comment: You are just adding more FUD, it still won't make him try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you represent the booleans as bits and serialise as binary, that is only about 8 kilobyte.

If you need is as text, serialise the binary using base64, that will make it about 12 kilobyte.

Flatten the two dimensional array to a one dimensional array, and make a `BitArray` from it.

Example:

```
bool[] bools = { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true };

BitArray bits = new BitArray(bools);
byte[] bytes = new byte[3];
bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);

Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

Outut:

```
FF-FF-0F
//8P
```

Comment: How would I "flatten" the array though? how would I recreate it from base64? so many questions...

Comment: @Max0999: Simply loop through the items in the array and copy them to a new array to flatten it. Use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get the bytes back from base64. Use `new BitArray(bytes)` to make a `BitArray` again, and the `CopyTo` method to copy the data into a `bool` array.

Comment: 255 * 255 = 65025 bits, which is 8129 bytes. Where are you getting 1.3k from?

Comment: @MarcGravell: You are right, of course. My calc fu seems to be weak today. Perhaps I double tapped when dividing by 8... Corrected it. :)

Comment: @Guffa it decreased it to 75,5kb which is still too big

Comment: @Max0999: Hm... Then you are doing something wrong... The base64 string itself should be smaller than 12 kB...

Comment: @Guffa I deleted the serialized file and resaved again this time it's 2,8kb SUCCESS :) there is still one problem though when I deserialize the map and test it, it seems it doesn't load properly serialize:`bool[] tempArray = new bool[MapWidth * MapHeight];
for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
{
for (int ii = 0; ii < MapHeight; ii++)
{
tempArray[i * ii] = mapSolid[i, ii];
}
}
BitArray bits = new BitArray(tempArray);
byte[] bytes = new byte[32 * MapWidth];
bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
bin.Serialize(stream, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));`

Comment: @Guffa and deserialize: `byte[] bytes = new byte[255 * 255];
bytes=Convert.FromBase64String((string)bin.Deserialize(stream));
MapWidth = (int)bin.Deserialize(stream);
MapHeight = (int)bin.Deserialize(stream);
BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);
bool[] bytestemp = new bool[255*265];
bits.CopyTo(bytestemp, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
{
for (int ii = 0; ii < MapHeight; ii++)
{
mapSolid[i, ii] = bytestemp[i*ii];
}
}`

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I would do would be: not store that data in a `bool[,]` - that is pretty inefficient, and a real pain to store. I would write a wrapper that shims it to a flat `byte[]`:

```
public sealed class BitGrid
{
    public BitGrid() {
        // 255 * 255 = 32 bytes per row, 255 rows
        bytes = new byte[8160];
    }
    public BitGrid(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (data.Length != 8160) throw new ArgumentException("data");
        this.bytes = data;
    }

    readonly byte[] bytes;

    public bool this[byte x, byte y]
    {
        get
        {
            int xByte = x / 8, xBit = x % 8;
            byte val = bytes[(32 * y) + xByte];
            switch (xBit)
            {
                case 0: return (val & 1) != 0;
                case 1: return (val & 2) != 0;
                case 2: return (val & 4) != 0;
                case 3: return (val & 8) != 0;
                case 4: return (val & 16) != 0;
                case 5: return (val & 32) != 0;
                case 6: return (val & 64) != 0;
                case 7: return (val & 128) != 0;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("oops!");
        }
        set
        {
            int xByte = x / 8, xBit = x % 8;
            int offset = (32 * y) + xByte;
            byte val = bytes[offset];
            if (value)
            {
                switch (xBit)
                {
                    case 0: val |= 1; break;
                    case 1: val |= 2; break;
                    case 2: val |= 4; break;
                    case 3: val |= 8; break;
                    case 4: val |= 16; break;
                    case 5: val |= 32; break;
                    case 6: val |= 64; break;
                    case 7: val |= 128; break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (xBit)
                {
                    case 0: val &= 254; break;
                    case 1: val &= 253; break;
                    case 2: val &= 251; break;
                    case 3: val &= 247; break;
                    case 4: val &= 239; break;
                    case 5: val &= 223; break;
                    case 6: val &= 191; break;
                    case 7: val &= 127; break;
                }
            }

            bytes[offset] = val;
        }
    }
    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        return (byte[])bytes.Clone();
    }
}
```

Then to serialize it, it is just:

```
byte[] data = grid.ToArray();
// store "data"
```

and to deserialize, it is just:

```
byte[] data = ...
grid = new BitGrid(data);
```

You can save / load a `byte[]` to/from disk using the `File.ReadAllBytes` / `File.WriteAllBytes` methods, or if you have other data to store, then any standard serializer will work fine with a `byte[]`. This data will always be 8160 bytes - just under 8k.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a (one-dimensional) [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) for serialization. This packs the bits into bytes.